# Unable to push app to bluemix through Command Line

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created a sample node.js app on bluemix. I could successfully connect and log-in to bluemix through cf cli.

I am trying to push my app to bluemix. But getting following error:

```
C:\Study\node-js-workshop-amitpl>cf app push node-js-workshop-amitpl
Showing health and status for app push in org AMSXYZ / space AMIT_Development as
 amit.xyz@xyz.com...
App push not found
FAILED
```

Tried following command, which failed as well:

```
C:\Study\node-js-workshop-amitpl>bluemix app push node-js-workshop
-amitpl
'bluemix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is wrong with above commands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cf command for pushing is:

```
cf push APP-NAME
```

So if `node-js-workshop-amitpl` is your APP-NAME, the following is what you need:

```
C:\Study\node-js-workshop-amitpl>cf push node-js-workshop-amitpl
```

Note that your previous command line was trying to run the `app` command which is used to retrieve the app status:

```
> cf app --help
NAME:
   app - Display health and status for app

USAGE:
   cf app APP_NAME

OPTIONS:
   --guid      Retrieve and display the given app's guid.  All other health and status output for the app is suppressed.

SEE ALSO:
   apps, events, logs, map-route, push, unmap-route
```

Comment: Great stuff.  Would you mind clicking the accept button and upvoting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the bluemix cli installed.

Can you try link below to install it? Note that bluemix cli does not come with cf cli.

https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html